# MySQL Query: add values from db1.table1 to db2.table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert into a table values from another database/table if some conditions are meet

## Populated Tables

### db1.table1

```
----------------------------------------------------
id  |  name  |  category_id |  value1   |   value2  
----------------------------------------------------
```

### db1.table2

```
--------------------
id | category
--------------------
```

## Table to be populated

### db2.table1

```
---------------------------------------------
id | name | category | value1 | value2
---------------------------------------------
```

Logic should be this:

Insert into `db2.table1.value1 and db2.table1.value2` values from `db1.table1.value1 and db1.table1.value2`.

IF this conditions are meet:

```
db1.table1.name = db2.table1.name
```

AND

```
db1.table2.category = db2.table1.category
```

table1 and table2 at db1 can be joined:

```
db1.table1.category_id = db1.table2.id
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a multi-table update.  You can reference multiple tables in a comma seperated fashion, and then use the WHERE clause to specify how they join.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

To make things easier, I've used aliases throughout.  It might not be exactly right as I may have misunderstood you but this essentially joins all three tables together and only where there is a full inner join match on the name field, will it update values.

```
update db2.table1 new, db1.table1 base, db1.table2 cat
set
new.category=cat.name,
new.value1=base.value1,
new.value2=base.value2
where 
new.name=base.name
and
base.category_id=cat.id
```

Answer (score 0):

An insertion can make it using the SELECT function
like:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table1(name, category, value1, value2) SELECT t1.name, t2.category, t1.value1, t1.value2 FROM db1.table1 as t1 INNER JOIN db1.table2 as t2 ON t1.id_category = t2.id;
```